# Python - Finding a motif - input: a txt file with 10 sequences and 10 motifs

Tags: python, phylogenetics, sequence-alignment, phylogeny, motifs

When I run my BruteForce function with only one input it works and the result is correct.

```python
def BruteForce(s, t):
    occurrences = []
    for i in range(len(s)-len(t)+1): # loop over alignment
        match = True
        for j in range(len(t)): # loop over characters
            if s[i+j] != t[j]:  # compare characters
                match = False   # mismatch
                break
        if match:   # allchars matched
            occurrences.append(i)

    print(occurrences) 

t = 'CAACTTCCA'

s = 'GACAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCGTCCCAACTTCACAACTTCGGCCCAACTTCCATGCAACTTCACCATCAACTTCGCTCGAAGCTGCCTTCCACTCCAACTTCACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCTCACCAACTTCAGCAACTTCTCTAGGGCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCAACTTCTCAACTTCCAACTTCCGACAACTTCTCCTGGCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCAATACAACTTCGCAGACAACTTCCGCAACTTCGAACAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCAACTTCAGATAGCAACTTCGATCTTACACAACTTCACGCAACTTCTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTGTGCAACTTCTCTGAACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCTCAACTTCATGCAACTTCGAGGCAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCTATTCCCAACTTCTGTGGCAACTTCTCAACTTCTGGACAACTTCTATGCCCAACTTCACAACTTCCCCAACTTCTTTACAACTTCGACAACTTCATCAACTTCTAGTCAACTTCTGGTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAAAGTGCCGCAACTTCGTAACAACTTCACGCGCTCAACTTCAACCAACTTCTTTTCCCGCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCTAATCAACTTCCAACTTCGGATCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCCAGGGACAACTTCAAGTACAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCTACACGCAACTTCCAACTTCTGGTCCCAACTTCATCAACTTCAGTCAACTTC'

BruteForce(s, t)

[2, 9, 48, 152, 175, 205, 212, 261, 277, 284, 300, 307, 370, 410, 607, 623, 717, 735, 751, 758, 792, 844]
```

But when I use it in the following loop it returns nothing! I have used the print() to see if it reads the strings and motifs from the input_2.txt file and it does but it returns an empty list of occurrences [].

```
with open('input_2.txt', 'r') as input_2:
    nt = input_2.readline() #nt is the no of strings+motifs in 1st line
    nt = int(nt) #in this case it is 10

    for i in range(nt):
        s = input_2.readline()
        print(s)
        t = input_2.readline()
        print(t)
        BruteForce(s, t)
```

Could you please let me know what changes are needed here? 
Many thanks,
Beeta

input_2.txt:

```
10

GACAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCGTCCCAACTTCACAACTTCGGCCCAACTTCCATGCAACTTCACCATCAACTTCGCTCGAAGCTGCCTTCCACTCCAACTTCACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCTCACCAACTTCAGCAACTTCTCTAGGGCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCAACTTCTCAACTTCCAACTTCCGACAACTTCTCCTGGCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCAATACAACTTCGCAGACAACTTCCGCAACTTCGAACAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCAACTTCAGATAGCAACTTCGATCTTACACAACTTCACGCAACTTCTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTGTGCAACTTCTCTGAACAACTTCCTCAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCTCAACTTCATGCAACTTCGAGGCAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCCTATTCCCAACTTCTGTGGCAACTTCTCAACTTCTGGACAACTTCTATGCCCAACTTCACAACTTCCCCAACTTCTTTACAACTTCGACAACTTCATCAACTTCTAGTCAACTTCTGGTCCAACTTCCAACTTCCCCAACTTCCAAAGTGCCGCAACTTCGTAACAACTTCACGCGCTCAACTTCAACCAACTTCTTTTCCCGCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCTAATCAACTTCCAACTTCGGATCAACTTCCAACTTCGCCAACTTCCAACTTCCAACTTCTCCAGGGACAACTTCAAGTACAACTTCCAACTTCGCAACTTCACAACTTCCCAACTTCGCAACTTCTACACGCAACTTCCAACTTCTGGTCCCAACTTCATCAACTTCAGTCAACTTC

CAACTTCCA

ATTGTGTATCGCTATGTATCGTGTATCGGATTTTGTATCGTGTATCGGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTATCACTGTATCGTTGTATCGTAGCGTTGTATCGTAATGTATCGCTCTGTATCGTGTATCGGGTTTGTATCGATGTGTATCGCTGTATCGGTGTATCGGTGTATCGCTTGTATCGACAGCGCTTGTATCGTGTATCGACCTGTATCGGTGTATCGTGTATCGAATGTATCGTTGTATCGAATTGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTATGTATCGACTGTATCGCTGTATCGTAGCCTGTATCGTGTATCGGTGTATCGGTGTATCGGCGTGTATCGAATGTATCGTTGTATCGCTGTATCGTGTGCTGTGTATCGGTGTATCGACCCGTTGTATCGTGTATCGTGGGTAAGTGTATCGTTGTATCGTAGTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTCATGGTATTGTATCGTTATAGCTGTATCGCTCGGCTGTATCGTATGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGCATGTATCGGTGTATCGCTGTATCGACCATGTATCGTGTATCGGTGTATCGATGTATCGCTTCCATTAGAAATGTATCGTATGTATCGTGTATCGCTGTATCGTTTGTATCGCATGTATCGATTGTGTATCGTGTATCGTTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTTGTATCGTAATAACGATGTATCGAATGATGTATCGTTGTGATGTATCGTGTATCGACTGTATCGATGTATCGGGTTGTATCGTGTATCGTGTATCGTAGATGTATCGAGAGCCATTGTATCGCCTTGTATCGCGTGTATCGGTGTGTATCGTTTGTATCGTGTTTGAATGTATCGCTGTATCG

TGTATCGTG

TTTCAGCGTGTTTGGCTTTCAGCACTACTTTCAGCGGTTTCAGCTTTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCTATTTTCAGCTTTCAGCCATCTTTCAGCCCAGGTTTCAGCTGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGAGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGCGGGGATTTCAGCGTATTTCAGCGACATTTCAGCAGTTTCAGCTGGAGTGAAGCCGTTTCAGCGCTTTTCAGCACCATTTCAGCTAGTAGGTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCTTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTATTTCAGCTCTAGAAGTCGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTCCTTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCAAACTTTCAGCGATTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCATTTCAGCTTTCAGCCGTTTTCAGCGACTCTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTGATCGTTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCGGTTTCAGCGAAAGTTGGTCTTTTCAGCCAAATTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCATTTCAGCCTATTTTCAGCAATCTTTCAGCAATTTTCAGCGCAATTTCAGCCAAAATTTCAGCATTTCAGCTTTCAGCGTAGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTGAGCCTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCTCTCTTTTCAGCTTTCAGCGATTTCAGCCTTTTCAGCGCTTTCAGCACCACGCCTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCCTTTCAGCCTATTTTCAGCGGTTTCAGCGTTTCAGCTTTCAGCACTTTCAGCTTTCAGCTTTTCAGCGGAAGGTTTTCAGCA

TTTCAGCTT

AGCATCCGACTGCATCCGTGCATCCGACGGCATCCGGCATCCGCAGCATCCGCACAGCCGCATCCGAGCCCGCATCCGAAGCATCCGGCATCCGGGCATCCGGCCGCATCCGGCATCCGGGCATCCGTGCATCCGGCATCCGTGTGCATCCGGCATCCGGGGTGCTTGCATCCGCGCATCCGTGCATCCGCGCATCCGGCATCCGCAGTCCGCATCCGCGCATCCGGCATCCGAGCATCCGTATTCGCATCCGTCGAGCATCCGTACGTCGCATCCGTGCATCCGGGAGAGGCATCCGGGCATCCGCGCATCCGGTGGACTATAACGCGCATCCGGCGAGCATCCGCCGCGGCATCCGTGCATCCGGTACGGCATCCGGGCTGAGGCATCCGCTCCCGGGGCATCCGCGGCGCATCCGCACGCGCATCCGGCATCCGAGCATCCGTTGCATCCGGAGCATCCGTAGCATCCGATAGCATCCGCAAGCTTGCATCCGGCATCCGCTACAGCATCCGGTGGCATCCGAAGCATCCGCGCATCCGCGGATTGCATCCGCACACGGCATCCGTAGCATCCGTGCATCCGGAGTGCATCCGCCGGGCGCATCCGCTGCATCCGCAGCGCATCCGAGCATCCGATCTTGCATCCGGCATCCGGGAATGCATCCGGGACTGCATCCGGTCTTAAGGGTGCATCCGAATGCATCCGCTGTAGCATCCGGCATCCGAGTAAGCATCCGAGTTCTGCATCCGGAAGCAGCATCCGGCATCCGGACACCAGCATCCGCGCATCCGGGGCGAGCATCCGAGCATCCGGCATCCGGGGCAAGTGGCATCCGGCATCCGTCGTGCATCCGGGCATCCGAA

GCATCCGGC

GACGAGCTGACGAGCGTGACGAGCAGGCGACGAGCGACGAGCATGCGGTGACGAGCGGACGAGCGACGACGAGCGCGGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCTCCGACGAGCGACGAGCACGACGAGCGCCCGACGAGCGACGAGCATGATGACGAGCGACGAGCTTAGACGAGCATGCTGACGAGCTGACGAGCTGACGAGCTCGTACATCGACGAGCGGACGAGCAGCCCGATAAGCCTTCGACGAGCTGACGAGCCACGACGAGCGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCGGGACGAGCGTCGGACGAGCGGACGAGCAGGACGAGCACCTCAATCGACGAGCTGACGAGCGGACGAGCCGACGAGCTGAACTGAAGGACGAGCCTACGTTCTAACGTGCCGTCACTGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCGATGGACGAGCTGACGAGCGCAGGACGAGCGAGAAGGCTGACGAGCAGACGAGCTGACGAGCTCGACGAGCAGACGAGCGGACGAGCTTTGATAAGACGAGCACGTCGACGAGCCTCGTGACGAGCTGACGAGCGACGAGCTAGACGAGCGACGAGCTGACGAGCGACGAGCACTAAACGCGACGAGCTCGACGACGAGCATGGACGAGCGACGAGCTAGGACGAGCGGCGACGAGCAGACGAGCGACGAGCTGACGAGCTTATAGACGAGCCTGACGACGAGCCAAGACGAGCGACGAGCGGACGAGCGACGAGCACGACGAGCCGACGAGCCGCGGACGAGCCGTAGACGAGCCAATCATTAAGACGAGCCGACGAGCCATTTGGGGACGAGCCTCCTCGACGAGCCATAAGACGAGCTGACGAGCCATGACGAGCATGCCCGACGAGC

GACGAGCGA

GAGGACCCCGGACCCCTGGACCCCAGGACCCCGACGGTGGGGCGGACCCCGAGAAGGACCCCTGGACCCCCGCAGGACCCCTTTATCGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCCGGACCCCGGCTGGACCCCGTCGTAAGGACCCCGAATCGGACCCCTAGGACCCCAGGGACCCCTCCCCGGTTGGACCCCCTGGACCCCCTTGAGAGGGACCCCGGACCCCACGCCGTGCTTAAGGACCCCACTATGGACCCCATACGGACCCCGGACCCCGATCAGAGCGACCAGGACCCCCGGCCTGGACCCCTCGGACCCCAGAAGGACCCCTCGGACCCCTGGACCCCGGACCCCACAGGGACCCCGGACCCCTAGCCGCGGTGGACCCCCGGACCCCCGCAGATGGGGACCCCTCATGCGGACCCCCTGACGGACCCCTGGACCCCCGGGACCCCCAGGGACCCCATTTCGAGGACCCCATGGGGACCCCAAGCTGGACCCCGGACCCCTGGGACCCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCATAGGACCCCCGTTTGTTGCCATGGACCCCTTGGGACCCCGAGTCGGACCCCGGACCCCCAGGACCCCACAGGACCCCGGGACCCCGGACCCCATCGATCGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCTACGGACCCCGCTAAGGGACCCCGGACCCCGTGGACCCCCACGGACCCCTAGGACCCCGGGACCCCGGACCCCGGACCCCAGTTGGACCCCCCTTAGGACCCCAGGACCCCACATGAGGACCCCGGGACCCCGGGACCCCTGGACCCCTGGACCCC

GGACCCCGG

AAACCTTCGGACCTTCGTACCTTCGACCTTCGTGAAACCTTCGGACCTTCGTGACCTTCGGGTGACCTTCGGGTACTCACCTTCGGCACCTTCGTATACCTTCGAGACCTTCGCTGGACTGTAAACCTTCGATCGTTATTTTCTACCTTCGCACACCTTCGACCTTCGAGCCGAACCTTCGGACTGGCCTCACCTTCGATCACCTTCGACCTTCGAACCTTCGACCTTCGACCATACCTTCGACCTTCGGACCTTCGGACCTTCGCACCTTCGAACCTTCGCCACCTTCGACCTTCGAACCTTCGGTGGGCCACCTTCGTTACCTTCGAACCTTCGGGCACCTTCGACCTTCGGCTTACACCTTCGGACCTTCGATGACTGACCTTCGAAACCTTCGACCTTCGACCTTCGATTCCACACCTTCGACCTTCGACACCTTCGACCTTCGCGTTCACCTTCGACCTTCGACCTTCGGGCCAATACCTTCGACCTTCGGCCTAATACCAACCTTCGAACCTTCGAACCTTCGGGTGACCTTCGGACCTTCGCGCACACCTTCGCACTTACCTTCGACCTTCGGTGACCTTCGACCTTCGTGCACCTTCGCGTCTCACCTTCGCACCTTCGTTACCTTCGAACCTTCGACCTTCGACAACCTTCGTACCTTCGCTACCTTCGGGAACCTTCGATGTCCTACCTTCGACCTTCGCGACCTTCGACCTTCGTAACCTTCGAACCTTCGACCACCTTCGAACCTTCGAAGGAAGGACCTTCGAATCATTACCTTCGTTACCTTCGTAGTACCTTCGCCGACCTTCGGACCTTAACCTTCGTGA

ACCTTCGAC

AAGTGGTATTCCCAAAAAGATATTCCCGTTATTCCCGCTATAAATATTCCCAACTGTTTATTCCCACTTATTCCCGTATTCCCGTATTCCCCGGGCCTTTTATTCCCCATTCTATTCCCGTATTCCCATATTCCCACTTATTCCCCTATTCCCATATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCGTAAGTATTCCCCCCCTTATTCCCCCATTTGTCCATATTCCCTCAATATTCCCTATTCCCCTATTCCCGCTTCCCCAGTCTATCCCAAATTGTATTCCCAATATTCCCCTTTATTCCCTTTATTCCCGTATTCCCTATTCCCGTGGCTATTCCCCCGACGTTATTCCCTCTATATTCCCGTCTCAAAGTATTCCCTTATTCCCAGTATTCCCATTCGCCTGGTATTCCCGTATTCCCGGTATTCCCGTTTATTCCCATCTATTCCCATTATTCCCTGGTATTCCCGCTATTCCCGCAACGGTATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCAATATTCCCTTCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCTAGCTATTCCCATATTCCCGATATTCCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCTATTCCCTAGTTATTCCCAAACAGGCTATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCATATTCCCTTATTCCCTACGTATTCCCTCTTAAAAATATTATTCCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCGTATTCCCCGAAAGTATTCCCCCATATTCCCAATTATATTCCCGGTATTCCCCCGTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCATATTCCCATATTCCCAAAGTTTATTCCCGTATTCCCCACTATTCCCATAGATTATTCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCCTATTCCCTATTCCCTTATTCCCGTATTCCCAGTTTATTCCC

TATTCCCTA

GAAAGGATAAAGGATGTCAAAGGATGCAGATATAAAGGATAAAGGATACAAAGGATTAAGTATGTCCGAAAAAGGATAAAGGATTAAAAGGATCGCTGAACCTTACACAAAGGATAGTGAACAAAGGATTCAATAAAAGGATAAAGGATCAAAGGATCAAAAGGATACAAAGGATGCCGATGAAAGGATAAAGGATCTAAAGGATAAAGGATGAGAAAGGATTGGAAAGGATTATGAGATCAAAGGATAAAGGATGGTGTAAAAGCTAAAGGATTCGGCAAAGGATAAAGGATTAAAGGATAAAAAGGATAAAGGATGAAAGGATCCGCAGGGACCAGCAAAAGGATAAAGGATCGAATGGGTAAGAAAGGATCAAAGGATGAAAAAGGATTACTAAAGGATAAAGGATCCTGAAAGGATTACAAAGGATCTTAAAAGGATTCGGAAAGGATCCATAGGAAAAGGATAAAGGATCGCGAAAGGATAAAGGATTAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAAGGATTCAAAGGATAAAGGATAGACAAGGGAGAAAGGATGCAAAGGATGAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAGGATTAGGTTAAAGGATCGAAAGGATCCAAAGAGAGCGAAAAGGATGAGGACGAAAGGATCAAAGGATCCAAAGGATCAAAGGATAAAGGATTGCGATGGAAAGGATGTCAAAGGATCACCAAAGGATAAAGGATAATAAAGGATAAAGGATAAAGGATCAAAGGATTTGAAAAGGATAAAGGATCACGAAAGGATAAAAGGATTGGCAAAGGATGAAAAGGATGAAAGGATAAGCCCTCCAAAGGAT

AAAGGATAA

ATTCAAATACTTCAAATAGTCAAATATCAAATATGCTTCAAATATCAAATATCGGTCAAATAAGTCAAATAAGTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATACTCAAATATCAAATAGTGTCAAATACGAATTGGGTCAAATATCAAATATGTGTTCAAATATTCTTCAAATACTGGACACTCAAATAGGAGTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATACGTGAAGTGCTTGTCAAATATTTCAAATACTTTCAAATATTCAAATACTCAAATATGTTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATTTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATAGTCCTCAAATAGCAAACCAGTCAAATATCAAATATGTCAAATATGCTCACGGCAACCTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATAGATGTCAAATAAGTTTCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATCAAATATTCAAATATCAAATAGCGGGCTCAAATAAGCTCAAATACGTCAAATAGGGGGTCAAATAGATCAAATAGTCAAATATTCAAATACATCAAATAGTCAAATACAAGAACCACCGAGATCTCAAATAATCAAATATCAAATATGGTCAAATAAATATTCAAATAGGTCAAATAAGATCAAATATCAAATAAGTCGTCCATCAAATAGTCAAATAGCTCAAATAACCTCAAATATCAAATATTCAAATACCGGTCATCAAATAGGACAAATCAAATAGTCAAATAAGATCCTCTCAAATAATTCAAATAGCTGTTCAAATACTCAAATATCAAATAGTCAAATATCAAATATTCAAATATCAAATACTTCAAATATGTTCAAATAATCAAATACTCAAATATCAAATAATCAAATAATACTTCAAATATACCAAACGCTCAAATATTAGTTGGATCAAATATCTTCAAATATCAAATAA

TCAAATATC
```

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting, but please check and make sure I didn't screw anything up. For help with formatting, please see [formatting tools](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: why not to use kmp? https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_di_Knuth-Morris-Pratt

Answer (score 5):

Let's start by doing some explaining about why your code doesn't work.

```
with open('input_2.txt', 'r') as input_2:
    nt = input_2.readline() #This is reading the first line of the file (which is 10)
    nt = int(nt) # this is storing "10" as an int

    for i in range(nt): # This is the same as "for i in range(10):" which just returns nums 0-9, does not access lines of your file
        s = input_2.readline() # this is reading the second line which is blank 
        print(s) # this will print a blank line 10 blank lines
        t = input_2.readline() # this is reading the rest of the file
        print(t)
        BruteForce(s, t) # this is calling your function on 10 blank lines and the restof your file, not each seq/motif
```

I made some modifications that will help you achieve your goal I think:

```
def BruteForce(s, t):
    occurrences = []
    for i in range(len(s)-len(t)+1): # loop over alignment
        match = True
        for j in range(len(t)): # loop over characters
            if s[i+j] != t[j]:  # compare characters
                match = False   # mismatch
                break
        if match:   # allchars matched
            occurrences.append(i)

    print(occurrences)

def group(lst, n):
    """ This function will be used to group your sequences and motifs later """
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        val = lst[i:i+n]
        if len(val) == n:
            yield tuple(val)

with open('input_2.txt') as input_2: #standard open in read mode, 
    lines = input_2.readlines()[2:] # skip 10 and the blank space bc we don't care about them
    split_line = [line.strip('\n') for line in lines if line!='\n'] #this will store lines that aren't blank into a list and strip new_line chars '\n'
    seq_tuple = list(group(split_line, 2)) # this will use group func above to group the list into tuples of 2's which are sequence and motif.

for x in seq_tuple: # this accesses the list of tuples (seq_tuple)
    BruteForce(x[0], x[1]) # x[0] in each tuple is seq, or BruteForce(s), x[1] in each tuple is motif, or BruteForce(t)
```

Running this will output Each motifs start position in each sequence:

```
[2, 9, 48, 152, 175, 205, 212, 261, 277, 284, 300, 307, 370, 410, 607, 623, 717, 735, 
751, 758, 792, 844]
[14, 33, 48, 55, 116, 192, 217, 253, 260, 267, 312, 370, 405, 412, 445, 452, 511, 
518, 561, 613, 657, 672, 679, 735, 769, 776, 847]
[37, 46, 64, 103, 120, 226, 243, 277, 284, 296, 303, 318, 345, 352, 359, 366, 381, 418, 439, 488, 495, 510, 590, 608, 628, 648, 697, 704, 748, 764, 771]
[29, 80, 95, 105, 128, 145, 191, 219, 328, 423, 489, 642, 713, 758, 808, 831]
[28, 57, 77, 102, 129, 148, 258, 265, 404, 419, 449, 553, 569, 584, 629, 664, 713, 728]
[2, 87, 94, 109, 204, 254, 332, 350, 487, 511, 518, 577, 603, 611]
[18, 154, 201, 216, 223, 235, 283, 339, 390, 397, 418, 425, 434, 453, 460, 481, 565, 582, 637, 644, 695, 711, 735]
[154, 161, 221, 303, 476, 483, 526, 554, 569, 584, 591, 617, 624, 647, 685, 754, 829, 836, 859]
[1, 33, 70, 135, 182, 198, 241, 279, 294, 303, 340, 395, 460, 478, 493, 500, 517, 559, 566, 573, 661, 704, 711, 721, 728, 754, 772, 808]
[19, 37, 44, 73, 80, 95, 128, 184, 191, 263, 270, 286, 293, 327, 364, 371, 400, 407, 414, 421, 436, 561, 609, 659, 754, 769, 784, 826, 886, 896]
```

Comment: Yes, yes, yes! You are right (and I feel very dumb), I should have paid attention to removing \n. All the times I spent on this problem.... I am thinking I could have changed the input file to something without any blank line and see how different the output would be. Thank you SO much for your time and your courtesy. I truly appreciate it. You have no idea how much this pipsqueak problem has been bugging me since yesterday. Thank you!

Comment: No problem! I’m happy to help, and welcome to the site! Going forward most bioinformatics file formats will utilize ‘\n’, ‘\t’, or ‘,’ as file separators in some form or another so it is good good to remember quick ways (like the list comprehensions above) to quickly manage those in your files. Thanks for your comment, it was very kind!

Answer (score 3):

This looks hard work. In Perl the function "index" and "rindex" as well as "substr" will perform this without the incremental loop. There must be an equivalent in Python?

I've not tried this, but at a guess it would be something like,

```
my @array;
my $target = 'AGATAGAGAGATAGAGAGATAGAGAGATAGAGAGATAGAG';
my $query = 'AGAGA';
while(length($target) > 4){
    my $location = index ($query, $target);
    push @array, $location;
    $target = substr ($location, length($target), $target);
}
print join("\s", @array), "\n";
```

Comment: Thank you! There is the find() method which returns ONLY the first occurrence (not all of them). But I just found out that I haven't tried Regex in python.

Comment: Perl is the same. The idea is that if you use it recursively with a "string splicing" algorithm you can get all your motifs easily and low computuational overheads. Please check "find()" for something like rfind() .. which does the same thing from the oppositive side of the string. That can be useful because when find() = rfind() then all the motifs in the string have been identified.